# Android Write file to a different application folder

Tags: java, android, root

- My device is rooted
- The target audience (if app is shared) will be rooted devices only

I'm trying to customize another app slightly by modifying some image files. So objective is to simply overwrite tiny jpg files (one at a time as required)

`/data/data/com.otherapp/files/somefile.jpg` for example needs to be overwritten

`p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");` is already run before I tried the write method.

I also added `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 077 " +myFile.getAbsolutePath());` before the write code as suggested on a similar question

I'm getting permission denied.
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com......jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`

The write code I have is:

```
    //myDir is /data/data/com.......
    File myFile = new File (myDir.getAbsolutePath(), fname);
    try {
        //myFile.createNewFile();//tried with and without this
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
        btbmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: The same task writing to SD Card no problem at all. `uses-permission etc all set correctly`

Comment: from what i know, one app can not access other's app private files (on the install directory for example)

Comment: @SkarosIlias yes normally not possible but with root it can as other answers have stated this but without any info on `how to`

Comment: i didnt know that about root. i thought that there is just no way of doing it. live to learn

Comment: Does both your `exec()` commands execute fine?? Did you check their errorstreams for possible failures???

Comment: @AbishekManoharan Yes both were fine. No exceptions. Just tested again to ensure there were no messages

Comment: I hope your `exec` did a `chmod 777` instead of `chmod 077`. That would revoke the permissions for the current user.

Comment: Even if the device is rooted then still your app should request root permissions first. Did you do that? And did your app got them? Can your app write on any other place already which requires root?

Comment: Yes the popup came up to `grant access` and I accepted. Is there a write test I can do? Please note that I'm not even sure if I'm doing this right. What would be the method? I'm really trying here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay it's taken all day but I've achieved the desired result thus:

- Create file on SD card
- Then copy file to root destination

`src_file = "somefile/on/sdcard.jpg"`

`dest_file = "/data/data/com.anotherapp/files/abcde.jpg"` got path using context

```
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
        os.writeBytes("rm "+dest_file + "\n"); //removes destination file -might not be required - haven't tested
        os.flush();
        os.writeBytes("cat "+src_file+" > "+dest_file + "\n");
        os.flush();
        os.writeBytes("exit\n");
        os.flush();

        // Waits for the command to finish.
        process.waitFor();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Note** In some cases I had to chmod the root folder 777 for it to work. I'm sure this isn't good practice and doing so will mean the app that uses that folder might not be able to access it. In my case that's what happened until I rectified it using ES Explorer